# Add custom profile info into Feed

Tags: feed, profiles

I have a few extra custom fields added into a user's profile and output them in several places within the frontend. One thing I want to do is add some of those custom fields into the WordPress Feed as RSS elements. As an example, I know that the Author Display Name is output by default but also want to add their Twitter handle into the feed too.

Anyone know a solution to this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out either the [`the_content_feed`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content_feed) and `the_excerpt_rss` filters or use the regular content and excerpt filters with the [`is_feed`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed)  conditional function.

The following should get you on the right track:

```
function wpse_140401_add_to_feed( $content )
{
    $twitter_handle = /* grab handle */;

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $content .= '<p>' . $twitter_handle . '</p>';
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'wpse_140401_add_to_feed' );
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wpse_140401_add_to_feed' );
```

Note that given the fact that the above uses filters applied to feeds only, the conditional isn't strictly necessary.